# postfix - smtp_address_preference: unknown parameter

Tags: debian, postfix

I'm trying to change the source IP of my mailing server from IPv6 to IPv4.

I'm running Debian 6.0.7 with Postfix 2.7.1 mail service and ISPConfig 3.0.5.1.

I found lots of forums saying that is easy as change the parameter `smtp_address_preference = any` to `smtp_address_preference = ipv4` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` config file, but I can't find this parameter in that file, and if I run `postconf smtp_address_preference` command it prompts `smtp_address_preference: unknown parameter`.

I tried adding it and reloading the service with no luck...
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing bad?

Thanks!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Comment: `smtp_address_preference` has been replaced by `inet_protocols`. See the Postfix manual: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smtp_address_preference was a part of the 2.8 update

you should look into: inet_protocols = ipv4

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, the Postfix manual states: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_protocols